# d3 js circle packing with children on perimeter

Tags: javascript, d3.js, circle-pack

There is a d3.js circle packing example where the children are displayed within their parent circle:

http://strongriley.github.io/d3/ex/pack.html

Are there any examples where the children are displayed on the perimeter of the parent circle?

For example, I would like the data to be displayed like this:

[image]

Instead of it being displayed like this:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looking at the graphs you want reminded me of this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vS8hJ/) that the great Lars Kotthoff put together when answering another question. Does not use any specific layout but could be a starting point. An FYI.

Comment: this looks very close! thanks dude!